# Как присвоить новый класс группе div'ов с одним классом?

Tags: javascript, html

Как средствами js присвоить каждому из блоков c классом "col", находящихся внутри блока "block" новый класс?

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>Описание</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>Описание</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>Описание</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const cols = document.querySelectorAll('.block .col');

cols.forEach(elem => {
  elem.classList.add('myClass');
})
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
</div>
```